# Automation - Stealing a signal from a circuit

Tags: pcb, signal-processing

I am a software designer (for reference).  I struggle with electronics and signals.

I have a device that has a microswitch that completes a circuit with a PCB.  I would like a way for that microswitch to trigger the action on the PCB as well as a USB key encoder attached to a computer.  Essentially, one trigger sending to two destinations.  The microswitch (leaf switch) works with both systems, but you obviously can just hook both sources and grounds to the switch and expect it to send to both.

Is there a way to know when source one has completed the circuit?  I know I am not the first person to ask this, but I could not figure out a similar question asked (probably because it is an impossibility that everyone else in the world understands except me).

I am trying to avoid using an additional micro switch on the same trigger.

Comment: Why can't you wire the same switch to both devices? Could you draw the actual circuit so that people can give you specific answers?

Comment: you need to describe the device because of possible high voltages .... you post is too wordy ... something simple like `I have an automatic coffee maker and i would like to generate an external signal whenever the brew button is pressed. How would I do that safely?`

Comment: I used opto isolators as mentioned in the OP. It required getting an additional small power source to attach, but it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It quite probable the the switch can't simply be connected to both circuits without them interacting in some undesired way. (this may involve smoke)

There's a couple of options

1: replace the switch with a two-pole switch (a two pole switch contains two separated switches that act in unison) and wire one pole of the switch to each circuit

2: keep the switch but use it to operate a two pole relay (a relay is an electrically operated switch)  it may be possible to take the power to operate the switch-relay circuit from one of the devices

3: add an isolated current sensor in series with the switch anuse that to detect switch closure and the current sensor operate a relay etc... this requires that the switch switches sufficient curren to operate the current sensor.

then theres's some options:

use two single-pole relays instead of a two pole relay.

find a way to use the switch in one circuit and have it also switch the relay (then only a single pole relay is needed)

use opto-isolators instead of relays: if the signals are small and switch resistance is not a problem this may work, opto-isolators are cheaper. smaller. and use less power, but their output capacity is much less that that of a relay.